# Deployment Project: File System: add shortcut to a folder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, deployment, deployment-project

In VS 2008, I'm trying to create a shortcut in the start menu to a folder in the application folder. So far, it appears that all I'm allowed to target is files. Is there someting I'm missing here, or is there a hack to getting this made?

Answer (score 0):

And I discover the answer not 10 seconds after I post:

1. Right Click on target folder
2. Select "Create Shortcut To..."
3. Move shortcut to desired location
4. Profit!

Hopefully this helps someone else.